# UNIX ACL disadvantages

Tags: permissions, acl

I have read a lot about how great UNIX ACLs are. For example, one good example can be viewed [here](http://www.fitzlong.com/documents/Access%20Control%20Lists%20vs%20File%20Permissions.pdf). However, are there any disadvantages or configurations that cannot be expressed using ACL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will probably get closed for soliciting opinions or being too broad but I'll do my best. "UNIX ACL" is a really indirect way of referring to it. I'm supposing you mean POSIX-style ACL's. The chief drawbacks there are with the lack of expressiveness in the number of operations you can specify since it just extends the traditional read/write/execute permissions such that you can specify more users than just the owner and more groups than just the file's primary group.

Most of these limitations aren't really important though, and rwx does what most people want. Other access controls usually get to "close enough" territory once you factor in file attributes such as making a file immutable or append-only (via `chattr`).

There are other ACL implementations than just POSIX, though. There's one out there for implementing NFS ACL's at the filesystem level called [richacls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richacls) but support is incomplete for the time being.

POSIX ACL's also don't really control capability execution on their own. They had to add that ability to SELinux so that you could do things like give a user `CAP_CHOWN` in general but restrict them from doing that with files that have a particular SELinux type.

Comment: +1 to the A, but still voted to close the Q as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other disadvantages than mantaining the files and directories tend to be more fine grained and the organization of people and groups could be messy.

So the ACL allows you to cover any scenario because it allows you to give the permissions as fine as you want so there is no scenario that can scape.

As a resume, the majority of scenarios could be covered with "traditional" UNIX permissions. When you need to share some directories or files with heterogeneus people with heterogeneus roles, the ACL give you the golden bullet you need to do it.